# TCPDF gray outline on transparent PNG

Tags: pdf-generation, png, tcpdf

I'm creating pdfs that have a PNG image with transparency, it almost works fine, but the PNG have a grey border around anything that isn't transparent.

[PNG in PDF](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mYq0s.png)

[Original picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BPAGX.png)

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

In Adobe's PDF viewer, you can turn it off with Preferences > Page Display > Rendering > Smooth images: NO

Reference
https://forum.openoffice.org/en/forum/viewtopic.php?f=7&t=22920&start=0

Answer (score 0):

It might just be an oddity in the PDF viewer you are using. Try a different viewer and see if that helps.

As a general rule I try to avoid using transparent pngs in PDFs, regardless of which library I'm using, due to potential performance issues and printing issues on some printers. If possible, try to replace transparency with white background - then you know you won't have any issues.

Comment: Unfortunately the problem is present in different viewer.
I can not use white as background - Image has rounded corners and should overlap the another picture.

Some people are advised to use a mask instead of transparency.